# Incrementing int to create a HashMap

Tags: java, android, json

I'm just updating my list view by getting data with the help of JSON, however I want to do this every 5 seconds, by incrementing a counter, meaning; when the counter>=5 after it gets data then set the counter to 0, so it will refresh again when it is 5.

Getting the data works perfectly, without the if sentence that checks for the counter value.

I'm not sure where I should type the if statement to get the results when the if sentence is true.

Here is my entire class;

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {
 int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
 int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
 int counterr=0;
 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;
 public boolean refresh=false;
 // Creating JSON Parser object
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

 // url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://XXXXXXX.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);
    //counterr=100;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           // Your code

            counterr++;
            System.out.println("COun "+counterr);
            System.out.println("Refresh?  "+refresh);

            if(counterr>=3)
                refresh=true;
        }
    }, delay, period);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            System.out.println(success);

            if (success == 1){// && counterr>=5) {

                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);


                    //if(counterr>=5){
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, "" + price);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                    counterr=0;
                    refresh=false;
                    }
                        }

                //counterr=0;
    // }

          else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.description });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to come up with a simpler example, I'm afraid --- I can't tell what it is that you think is going wrong. Can you simplify it down the the barest minimum needed to manifest the problem? Ten lines of code or so would be good. (Apart from anything else, when *I* have a problem like this, trying to reduce it to a test case frequently shows me what's wrong and I get to fix it myself.)

Comment: The problem I think is, my program doesn't go through this class more than once, if it did loop the entire code 5 times at least, it would know the counter is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By implementing this; inside the public void run(){

```
  if(counterr>=5){
    counterr=0;
        json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
  }
```

Does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need not to put any if condition in TimerTask. If you want to start the timer after 5sec and next request every 5sec. than make

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 5000; // repeat after every 5 sec.
```

In case you want to start the task immediately than reduce the delay to its minimum.

Give a try hope it will work.

Comment: No problems with the timer, however, counter works but, I want to get stuff from JSON when the counter is>=5.