# int set to zero generates new int by the same name tho

Tags: java

When I create an `int COun` that increments with the following function, once it gets to desired int to set it back to zero, the `COun` is set to zero and starts incrementing again until 10 but it increments another int, by the same name I assume. Why does it do that?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           // Your code

            counterr++;
            System.out.println("COun "+counterr);
           // System.out.println("Refresh?  "+refresh);
             if(counterr>10){
                 json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 counterr=0;

             }
        }
    }, delay, period);
```

When you print out COun, you can tell it starts by just incrementing one COun, but then every time if sentence kicks in, it generates another COun counter.

```
12-20 18:50:16.170: I/System.out(10465): COun 1

12-20 18:50:17.071: I/System.out(10465): COun 2

12-20 18:50:18.082: I/System.out(10465): COun 3

12-20 18:50:19.083: I/System.out(10465): COun 4

12-20 18:50:20.084: I/System.out(10465): COun 5

12-20 18:50:21.085: I/System.out(10465): COun 6

12-20 18:50:22.086: I/System.out(10465): COun 7

12-20 18:50:23.077: I/System.out(10465): COun 8

12-20 18:50:24.078: I/System.out(10465): COun 9

12-20 18:50:25.079: I/System.out(10465): COun 10

12-20 18:50:26.080: I/System.out(10465): COun 11

12-20 18:50:27.071: I/System.out(10465): COun 1

12-20 18:50:28.082: I/System.out(10465): COun 2

12-20 18:50:29.073: I/System.out(10465): COun 3

12-20 18:50:30.083: I/System.out(10465): COun 4

12-20 18:50:31.084: I/System.out(10465): COun 5

12-20 18:50:31.405: I/System.out(10465): COun 1

12-20 18:50:32.085: I/System.out(10465): COun 6

12-20 18:50:32.406: I/System.out(10465): COun 2

12-20 18:50:33.086: I/System.out(10465): COun 7

12-20 18:50:33.407: I/System.out(10465): COun 3

12-20 18:50:33.407: I/System.out(10465): COun 8

12-20 18:50:33.407: I/System.out(10465): COun 4

12-20 18:50:33.407: I/System.out(10465): COun 9

12-20 18:50:33.407: I/System.out(10465): COun 5
```

and it goes on weirdly like that, when either one becomes 10, it generates counting another one, along with the original, and on and on...

Comment: How are you invoking this code? Are you calling it twice by any chance?

Comment: I don't think you've included all of the relevant source.

Comment: the complete code is in this link as the question, you are right, void run() is implemented in the bottom of the class, but it is needed; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732039/incrementing-int-to-create-a-hashmap Basically I need this method to keep a counter, and at the end of it, set it back to zero, any alternatives?

Comment: What do you suppose `scheduleAtFixedRate()` does?

Comment: Runs the code every 5 seconds, as the delay and period variables determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute it once then you should call

```
schedule(TimerTask task,Date time)
```

or

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)
```

`scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task,long delay,long period)` is when you need it to run repeatedly.

Comment: in that sense; time has to be initialized at the top of the class as type Date; but what date to choose?

Comment: @user3125900, Whatever the time you need to execute it, If you need to execute it right after, then call the second method with 0 for the second argument ( i.e long delay)

Comment: The thing is, I wanted to constantly increase the counterr, it is an auto refresh mode, when counterr=10, basically it refreshes every 10 seconds. The void run() method is also in the bottom of the class is that why it doubles, or triples the third time when it reaches 10? You can review the full class' code from this link; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732039/incrementing-int-to-create-a-hashmap   the question there contains the entire class, you will see on the bottom it is implemented again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3125900, is there a possibility of  onCreate() method being invoked more than once?